# pandas - numpy using np.where to calculate and construct new columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column based on selection criteria in another column. This is at an end of a while loop so the data frame does not have the column until this part of the first iteration. All subsequent iterations will be based on this columns previous iteration's total and the current totals:

```
if 'cBeds' in sPhase.columns:
        sPhase['cBeds'] = np.where(sPhase['COUNTYFP'] == '1', (sPhase['cBeds'] + (sPhase[infCount] * .08)), sPhase['cBeds'])
else:
    sPhase['cBeds'] = np.where(sPhase['COUNTYFP'] == '1', (sPhase[infCount] * .08), sPhase['cBeds'])
```

However, when I run the code I get `'KeyError: 'cBeds'`

How can handle updating a column in a conditional when the column doesn't exist on the first iteration?

Comment: kindly share a sample of ur data, with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` clause, you reference `sPhase['cbeds']` as the third parameter to `np.where` even though you've already established that the column does not exist.

If you want to avoid this problem, just add the column at the beginning of the loop and give it a default value that you can conditionally change later.